# Fixie bike crank/pedals give in when back pedalling

Tags: brakes, crankset, pedals, fixed-gear

Recently was given a fixie, but with braking issues.

Whenever I back pedal (as in lock up and stop pedalling completely), the crank/pedal seems to give in and not stop the rear wheel from moving forward.

It’s like it reaches a limit of force, and then back pedalling to brake becomes impossible even after I’ve stopped pedalling/locked up - the rear wheel still moves forward/doesn’t skid or lock up as well.

Haven’t tried to fix anything just yet. Any and all suggestions would be much appreciated.

---

I weight about 160lbs (82 kg)

I’m putting enough downward pressure, so much that the crank gives in and turns backward while the rear wheel is moving forward.

I’ve ridden fixie in the past, so I understand the forward position and braking motion.

It feels like how you turn a plastic water bottle’s cap closed, so tight, that it then becomes loose - it what it feels like. I’ve also tried it again today, and pedalling forward does the same thing now.

Comment: lockring problem?

Comment: @Noise havent checked this.. will do

Comment: i think you have possibly destroyed the threads on the hub based on your last comment.

Comment: @Noise Lol how was that even possible. It wasn’t that did it, given to me like this. i weight about 160lbs. I .. don’t know how to fix it. Maybe poor quality hub. 

How would I fix this?

Comment: hub's only aluminium, loose lockring and repeated sprocket movement could have killed it. Could have been installed cross thread. All conjecture. You'll know when you disassemble. Only repair would be new hub/wheel unless existing hub is fix/fix

Comment: Consider that you were given a bike - its likely to have some kind of problem.  Perhaps this is why the bike was given to you ?

Comment: Yes, I mean if you just peddle easy it’s fine. There’s brakes on it to stop. It’s when you want to go much faster/brake harder…. It’s also a flipflop, so worse case I just freewheel it. 

I’ll try taking the pedals apart. Doesn’t seem to be anything wrong with the gear - more so what @Noise mentioned.

Comment: have you found a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fixed Gear crank arm slips](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50823/fixed-gear-crank-arm-slips)